# Reversing reputation earned after converting an answer to community wiki

Tags: discussion

In this [answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-are-the-recent-tcs-books-whose-drafts-are-available-online/3545#3545) the question wasn't originally community wiki and it was turned later into one. The answer was posted before it was community wiki and so I got rep for the upvotes. When I noticed I made the answer community wiki so I won't get further rep.

The question is how to reverse the rep. I got already ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reverse the reputation you have earned already and you don't need to. :)

(But if you want, you can put a bounty on some other question to give away that reputation.)

Comment: Nice :) I always wanted to put a bounty, thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Our users are way too honorable :)

Comment: I remember reading something about how that extra rep will disappear during the next database update.. or maybe it was about something else.

Comment: @Robin: I thought of that too (it is called “reputation recalculation” or “rep recalc”), but no, the rep recalc does not cancel the rep points earned for a post before it was turned to a CW.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16750/how-do-questions-marked-community-wiki-after-you-answer-impact-rep-upon-recalc/16800#16800.